# Wifi won't connect on Ubuntu 17.04 with Windows 8.1 dual boot

Tags: networking, dual-boot, drivers, wireless, realtek

I partitioned my SSD and installed Ubuntu 17.04 alongside Windows 8.1. When I boot into Windows, wifi connects and works perfectly. When I boot into Ubuntu and click the network icon, it shows all the same available connections, but when I make a selection it just tries connecting for 30 seconds before saying "Disconnected - you are now offline".

I'm a noob when it comes to Linux so I'll do my best to follow along. I'm using a TP-LINK TL-WN822N wireless adapter and a RTL8192CU wireless driver. I don't know if I have a problem in my settings, driver, or something else, but I've been looking at 'duplicate Qs' and posts with similar problems for days and haven't gotten anywhere, so I'd really appreciate some help troubleshooting this. Let me know what info I need to add.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are probably two things wrong. First, open a terminal by pressing Ctrl + Alt + T and run:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
```

Use nano or kate or leafpad if you don't have the text editor gedit. At the bottom of this file, copy and paste the following:

```
[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
```

The final result will look like this

```
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile

[ifupdown]
managed=false

[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
```

Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor and then run:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

Next, it is likely that you have two possibly conflicting drivers loaded. Check:

```
lsmod | grep rtl
```

I suspect that two drivers are listed, `rtl8xxxu` and also `rtl8192cu`. If so, you need just one. Again, from the terminal:

```
sudo -i
echo "blacklist rtl8192cu"  >>  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
modprobe -r rtl8192cu
exit
```

Any improvement? It might take a reboot.

Comment: `sudo -H` can be used instead of `gksudo` that, if I'm not mistaken, would need to be installed as it no longer comes by default.

Comment: Woo! It worked perfectly, thanks a bunch @chili555! Wish I had asked sooner. @MichaelBay you're correct, I had to use 'sudo' instead.